# Get Value of XML nodes using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I don't know how to get the value of the nodes path **Users/test/** and  **/var/root/** of this XML file using PowerShell.

I can read all paths until :

$xmlRead.backupConfig.backupSets.backupSet.backupPaths.pathset.paths

but i can't get the node path

here is the xml example :

```
<backupConfig>
  <backupSets>
    <backupSet id="1">
      <name>Backup</name>
      <priority>1</priority>
      <backupPaths>
        <lastModified>1550047373343</lastModified>
        <pathset>
          <paths os="Windows">
            <path include="/Users/test/"/>
            <path include="/var/root/"/>
          </paths>
        </pathset>
     </backupPaths>
  </backupSet>
```

Do you have any idea, how i can get these value ?

Thanks,